# see "partition doesn't exist" warning after partition reassignment

Tags: apache-kafka, cluster-computing, replication

After a partition reassignment, we saw partitions with no isrs and no leader. Restarting the controller solves this problem. Now all partitions have leaders.

However after that the consumers still fail to fetch.

We see "Fetching offset from leader xxx has failed" error messages.

And get "Offset request with correlation 0 from client ... Partition[xxx,xx] doesn't exist on x (kafka.server.KafkaApis)" warning.

What are the possible courses?

Comment: A related question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409605